# How use kde libraries in qt?

Tags: qt, kde-plasma

Excuse me for my bad English.
How use kde libraries in qt?
I search and google for this but without good answer.
cpp file

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <KDE/KWindowSystem>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    qDebug() << "Hello World";
//  bool wayland = KWindowSystem::isPlatformWayland();
//  qDebug() << wayland;
//  KWindowSystem::self();
    foreach (const auto &wid, KWindowSystem::self()->stackingOrder())      {
        qDebug() << "Hi";
    }
    return a.exec();
}
```

pro file

```
######################################################################
# Automatically generated by qmake (3.1) Tue Mar 7 02:09:59 2017
######################################################################

TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = firstqt
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/KF5/KWindowSystem .

# Input
SOURCES += main.cpp
LIBS += -lkdeui
```

I get error:
fish: “./firstqt” terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I search again and I found that LIBS += -lkdeui is for kde4 and it must be LIBS += -lKF5WindowSystem

Answer (score 0):

I search again and I found that LIBS += -lkdeui is for kde4 and it must be LIBS += -lKF5WindowSystem
now my code is
main.cpp

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <KWindowSystem>
#include <QDebug>

// using KWallet::Wallet;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    for(int i = 0; i < KWindowSystem::stackingOrder().count(); i++)
    {
        qDebug() << "Hi";
    }
    return a.exec();
}
```

and main.pro is

```
TARGET = wallet
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp
LIBS += -lKF5WindowSystem
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/KF5/KWindowSystem \
```

and kwindowsystem recognized but this only print a warning:

org.kde.kwindowsystem: Could not find any platform plugin

now what is problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change QCoreApplication to QApplication.
It seems, you have to state explicitly, that you are writing an application (not a plugin for kde).
For me the following code works fine:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <KWindowSystem>
#include <iostream>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  QList<WId> stackingOrder = KWindowSystem::stackingOrder();

  for ( auto wid : stackingOrder ) {
    std::cout << "wid=" << wid << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Compile as follows:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -fPIC -I/usr/include/KF5/KWindowSystem ./test.cpp -o test
`pkg-config --libs --cflags Qt5Widgets` -lKF5WindowSystem
```

My impression is, that the documentation around kde5/plasma is unfortunately very poor.

[The only tutorial for beginners I could find](https://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/First_program)

For more complex cases, you have to look directly in the [code_1](https://github.com/KDE/plasma-desktop/blob/master/applets/pager/plugin/pagermodel.cpp) or/and [code_2](https://github.com/KDE/plasma-workspace/tree/master/libtaskmanager)
The installation of development packages under e.g. debian is also not straight forward.